# React: Mutating state through setTimeout return wrong results

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of alerts as my state.

I'm trying to allow my users to dismiss an alert manually by clicking on it and also automatically after a couple of second.

Currently only the 3rd alert getting cleared automatically and the rest  are left untouched.

Can i even achieve my goal with the current implementation ?
if not what will be the right direction to explore ?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [alerts, setAlerts] = useState([
    { message: "Alert 1" },
    { message: "Alert 2" },
    { message: "Alert 3" },
    { message: "Alert 4" }
  ]);

  const dismissAlert = alertIndex => {
    setAlerts([
      ...alerts.slice(0, alertIndex),
      ...alerts.slice(alertIndex + 1)
    ]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Alerts alerts={alerts} dismissAlert={dismissAlert} />
    </div>
  );
}

const Alerts = ({ alerts, dismissAlert }) => (
  <div className="alerts">
    {alerts.map((alert, i) => (
      <Alert key={i} alert={alert} dismissAlert={() => dismissAlert(i)} />
    ))}
  </div>
);

const Alert = ({ alert, dismissAlert }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const timerId = setTimeout(dismissAlert, 1000);

    return () => {
      console.log("clearing timeout");
      clearTimeout(timerId);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="alert" onClick={dismissAlert}>
      <p>{alert.message}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[Online SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/92jqm9rkxy)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may need an alternative way to identify the alert that needs dismissing since the index may change between the time the dismiss is requested and the time the dismiss actually happens.

Comment: Apparently React didn't clear my `setTimeout` when updating `alerts` because it was getting the same `key` (i guess that's why `eslint` always complains about index as key) changing the `key` to `i + alert.message` fixed my problem.

Comment: I think it had another bug. 4 message should clear same time. But it clear sequential

Comment: Yes because the `Alert` rerenders and getting a new `setTimeout` when mounted, I'm trying to solve this now with `React.memo`.

Answer (score 0):

Check a modified example of your code, I think it works more or less how you intend to but it can have glitches. The thing which I felt was not working well, was dismissing alerts on setTimeout. It seemed like setTimeout was removing stuff which was may have already removed. So to keep it concurrent I am maintaining a queue which will hold the items to remove. Also I used `id` instead of relying on indexes which can be changed after splice. Let me know if you need further help.

By the way you need to work out on `setTimeouts`, reason why is after they get rendered, all of them will be scheduled to remove within a difference of split second which will give the feel that all of them were removed together

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(addAlert, 5000);
    setInterval(dismissAlert, 6000);
  }, []);

  const addAlert = () => {
    setAlerts([
      ...alerts,
      { id: new Date().getTime(), message: "new alert" + Math.random() }
    ]);
  };

  const [alerts, setAlerts] = useState([
    { id: 1, message: "Alert 1" },
    { id: 2, message: "Alert 2" },
    { id: 3, message: "Alert 3" },
    { id: 4, message: "Alert 4" }
  ]);

  const [alertsToRemove, addAlertsToRemove] = useState([]);

  const queueRemoval = alertId => {
    if (alertsToRemove.indexOf(alertId) <= -1) {
      alertsToRemove.push(alertId);
      addAlertsToRemove(alertsToRemove);
    }
  };

  const dismissAlert = () => {
    alertsToRemove.forEach(id => {
      var alertToDelete = alerts.find(a => a.id == id);
      alerts.splice(alerts.indexOf(alertToDelete));
      setAlerts(alerts);
    });
    addAlertsToRemove([]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Alerts alerts={alerts} queueRemoval={queueRemoval} />
    </div>
  );
}

const Alerts = ({ alerts, queueRemoval }) => (
  <div className="alerts">
    {alerts.map((alert, i) => (
      <Alert
        key={i}
        alert={alert}
        queueRemoval={() => queueRemoval(alert.id)}
      />
    ))}
  </div>
);

const Alert = ({ alert, queueRemoval }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const timerId = setTimeout(queueRemoval, 3000);

    return () => {
      console.log("clearing timeout");
      clearTimeout(timerId);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="alert" onClick={queueRemoval}>
      <p>{alert.message}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit jqo02movw]